# Как создать новую строку в UITextField когда нажимаю на Return на клавиатуре?

Tags: swift

Вот мой код

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @objc func onClickTop(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("ButtonTop is Clicked")
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    @objc func onClickBottom(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("ButtonBottom is Clicked")
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    private lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        return UITextField()
    }()
    
    private lazy var topBtn: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        btn.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn.setTitle("topBtn", for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()
    
    private lazy var bottomBtn: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        btn.backgroundColor = .green
        btn.setTitle("bottomBtn", for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        textField.placeholder = "HERE"
        textField.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        topBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(topBtn)
        topBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        topBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickTop(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        bottomBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bottomBtn)
        bottomBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickBottom(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на `Return` на клавиатуре то не создается новая строка, курсор дальше остается на той же строке

Как сделать так, чтоб создавалась новая строка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextField` спроектирован так, чтобы работать **только** с однострочным вводом текста. Для того, чтобы использовать многострочный ввод, используйте `UITextView`